# How can I solve this error: XML declaration allowed only at the start of document?

Tags: postgresql

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<level OPERATORE="maria bianca_amadeo" QUARTIERE="Quartiere 1 - Ricerca 
oggetti - Versione a" LEVEL="1" DATA="2016-04-18 17:59">
<track X="-237" Y="0" Z="155" TEMPO="0" />
<track X="-237" Y="0" Z="155" TEMPO="2" />
<track X="-238" Y="0" Z="155" TEMPO="4" />
<track X="-249" Y="0" Z="161" TEMPO="6" /> 
</level>
</root>
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION j_f_sync_from_xml()
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
myxml    xml;
datafile text := 'ABBATE_EMANUELE_Lvl1F2Va_20160418-1759.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 1, 100000000); 

CREATE TABLE james AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

SELECT j_f_sync_from_xml();
```

If I run select j_f_sync_from xml, postgres gives me an error XML declaration allowed only at the start of document, invalid XML content.
I controlled the xml file but there aren't others declarations.
THE ERROR IS AT LINE 1!

ERRORE:  invalid XML content
DETAIL:  line 1: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Comment: Is the above XML snippet against what you are actually running your query?

Comment: in the XML there aren't other declarations... but postgres gives me this error...

Comment: at the end of the XML there are <level> and <root> closing tag

Comment: at line 1 gives this error

Comment: Probably something to do with the way you read the file, because the XML string works just fine: http://rextester.com/TQTGL99724

Comment: pg_read_file (datafile, 1, 100000) but the error now is sequence of byte not valid for code UTF-8

Comment: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-admin.html): "*The bytes read from the file are interpreted as a string in the server encoding*" - I guess your server encoding is not UTF-8 then. Try to use `pg_read_binary_file()` and then use `convert_from()` to convert the `bytea` to `text` with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: How extract an x value from rextester.com/TQTGL99724?